# Append partial from ajax call

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm trying to append a partial with `ajax` but when I do it, it brings me the entire page (*adding again the menu and all elements*), what I want is to bring just the block.

This is what I have.

`#views/partials/avisos.blade.php`

```
@section('content')
  @foreach ($avisos as $aviso)
    <tr>
       <td>{{$aviso->aviso_id}}</td>
       <td>{{$aviso->Guia}}</td>
       <td>{{$aviso->Nombre_de_vendedor}}</td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
@stop
```

`#controllers/HomeController.php`

```
public function searchVentas(){
  $avisos = DB::table('avisos').... ->get();

  $this->layout->content = View::make('partials.avisos')->with('avisos', $avisos); 
}
```

`#views/ventas.blade.php`

```
$("#edicion_id").change(function(){
   var edicion_id = $(this).val();
   $( "#datepicker" ).val("");

   $.get("searchVentas",{edicion_id: edicion_id}, function(data){ 
       $("tbody").append(data);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
$this->layout->content = View::make('partials.avisos')->with('avisos', $avisos);
```

to

```
Return View::make('partials.avisos')->with('avisos', $avisos);
```

edit: but you need to change your partial file - because there will be no 'section' - so remove the @section like this

```
  @foreach ($avisos as $aviso)
    <tr>
       <td>{{$aviso->aviso_id}}</td>
       <td>{{$aviso->Guia}}</td>
       <td>{{$aviso->Nombre_de_vendedor}}</td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
```

The other option is make a 'blank' layout like this:

**app/views/layouts/blank.blade.php**

```
@yield('content')
```

Then just do this in your controller

```
$this->layout = View::make('layouts.blank');
$this->layout->content = View::make('partials.avisos')->with('avisos', $avisos);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!

I just couldn't do it with `$this->layout->content` so I change it as you first told me, to `Return`.

Comment: Thanks @robzdc - if this has solved your question please dont forgot mark my answer as 'accepted' - thanks